# member function implementation depending on template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

I have the following problem:

```
template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
class A
{  
  public:

    // ...

    // first implementation
    template< size_t M = sizeof...(N_i)+1, typename std::enable_if< M!=1, size_t >::type = 0 >
    A<T, N_i...> operator[]( size_t i )
    {
      A< T, N_i... > res{ ... };

      return res;
    }

    // second implementation
    template< size_t M = sizeof...(N_i)+1, typename std::enable_if< M==1, size_t >::type = 0 >
    T operator[]( size_t i )
    {
      return ... ;
    }
};
```

As you can see above, I try to implement a class `A` which expects as template arguments a type `T` (e.g. `int` or `float`) and `sizeof...(N_i)+1`-many `size_t`.

Dependent on the number of passed `size_t` (i.e. `sizeof...(N_i)+1`), I will use a different implementation for the member function `operator[](size_t)` with a different result type:

- one implementation for the case `sizeof...(N_i)+1 > 1` with return type `A < T, N_i... >`
  (referred to as "first implementation" in the code)
- and one for the case `sizeof...(N_i)+1 == 1` with return type `T` 
  (referred to as "second implementation" in the code).

Unfortunately, I have no idea how this can be implemented -- the solution above does not work. Has anyone an idea?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A<T, N_i...>` is invalid for empty `N_i`.
As workaround, you may use indirection:

```
template <typename, std::size_t ...>
struct PopFrontA
{
    using type = void; // Dummy type for A<T, N>
};

template< typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... N_i > class A;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t N2, std::size_t ... Ns>
struct PopFrontA<T, N, N2, Ns...>
{
    using type = A<T, N2, Ns...>;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Ns>
using PopFrontA_t = typename PopFrontA<T, Ns...>::type;
```

And then

```
// first implementation
template< size_t M = sizeof...(N_i)+1, typename std::enable_if< M!=1, size_t >::type = 0 >
PopFrontA_t<T, N, N_i...>
operator[]( size_t i )
{
  A< T, N_i... > res{ /*...*/ };

  return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a583d0128d2d98f6)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know why `A<T, N_i...>`does not cause an SFINAE error for empty `N_i`?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert: `A<T, N_i...>` doesn't depend of template parameter of the method. `A<T, N_i...>` is invalid for any value of template parameter of the method.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify

```
A< T, N_i... > res{ ... };
```

in

```
A< T, N_i... > res{ };
```

and

```
return ... ;
```

in

```
return T{} ;
```

isn't enough?

**--- EDIT ---**

No: as pointed by Jarod42 (thanks!), isn't enough.

So I propose the following solution, based on class template specialization and `std::conditional` to avoid the use of SFINAE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename, size_t...>
class A;

template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
class A<T, N, N_i...>
 {  
   public:
      template <typename Next = typename std::conditional<sizeof...(N_i),
                                           A<T, N_i...>, T>::type>
      Next operator[] (size_t i)
       { return Next{}; }
 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
 {
   A<int, 2, 4> a;

   std::cout << a[1][2] << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

If you don't want specialize `A`, you can add a sub-struct of `A` to do the dirty work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T, size_t N, size_t... N_i >
class A
 {  
   template <typename U, size_t ... O_i>
      struct Next
       { using type = A<U, O_i...>; };

   template <typename U>
      struct Next<U>
       { using type = U; };

   public:
      using next_t = typename Next<T, N_i...>::type;

      next_t operator[] (size_t i)
       { return next_t{}; }
 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
 {
   A<int, 2, 4> a;

   std::cout << a[1][2] << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You will have error once you instantiate `A<T, N>`. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70c3a96907dc600f)